# Jest has detected the following 1 open handle potentially keeping Jest from exiting

Tags: javascript, express, testing, jestjs

Here are my HTTP  routes

```
 app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).send('Hello World!')
})

app.post('/sample', (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).json({
        x:1,y:2
    });
})
```

I would like to test for the following

1) `GET` request working fine.

2)the  `/sample` response contains the properties and `x` and `y`

```
const request = require('supertest');
const app = require('../app');

describe('Test the root path', () => {
    test('It should response the GET method', () => {
        return request(app).get('/').expect(200);
    });
})

describe('Test the post path', () => {
    test('It should response the POST method', (done) => {
        return request(app).post('/sample').expect(200).end(err,data=>{
            expect(data.body.x).toEqual('1');

        });
    });
})
```

But I got the following error on running the test

> Jest has detected the following 1 open handle potentially keeping Jest
>   from exiting:
>
> return request(app).get('/').expect(200);

Answer (score 11):

you need to call `done()` in the `end()` method

```js
const request = require("supertest");
const app = require("../app");

let server = request(app);

it("should return 404", done =>
    server
        .get("/")
        .expect(404)
        .end(done);
});
```

Answer (score 9):

This trick worked;

```
afterAll(async () => {
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(), 500)); // avoid jest open handle error
});
```

As described in this [github issue](https://github.com/visionmedia/supertest/issues/520#issuecomment-469044925).

Answer (score -1):

Hi You can use the toEqual function as well

```
describe('Test the post path', () => {
    test('It should response the POST method', () => {
        return request(app).post('/sample').expect(200).toEqual({ x:1,y:2
        });
    });
})
```

There are lots of methods can be used instead.You can go throw the official documentation which covers every jest function https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect

Comment: Tried your answer but i got this error `Jest did not exit one second after the test run has completed`

Comment: You can go throw the docs there are several methods. Actually what is needed at your point is the way of calling. I have never used return request(app) in Jest Testing. I mainly used expect(To make call function).toEqual(To test its value) and it works perfectly fine for me

Comment: I am asking about the HTTP response from the  http post call

Answer (score -2):

As a general tip to debug this error, add `--detectOpenHandles` to your npm script that runs Jest e.g.

```
   "scripts": {
    ...
    "test": "jest --detectOpenHandles"
    }
```

This should tell you exactly which part of the code is causing the issue (probably some type of server connection, particularly if its `async`).

In general, if you can move the connection code to a separate function in a file outside of your tests, then import and call it in your tests, this will also fix the issue.