# Jest has detected the following 1 open handle potentially keeping Jest from exiting: TLSWRAP

Tags: typescript, axios, jestjs

writing an api integration test using jest and axiom.  I swear I had a simple version of this working when I had the bearer token hardcoded into the header of the put request.  But after some futzing I can't even ctr + z to get to where it was 'working' - and I can't get rid of this error:

```
Jest has detected the following 1 open handle potentially keeping Jest from exiting:

  ●  TLSWRAP

      13 |
      14 |   it('user can create a cart', async () => {
    > 15 |     const response = await axios.put(
```

I have tried fixes these fixes, but no dice.

- https://jestjs.io/docs/asynchronous
- [Jest has detected the following 1 open handle potentially keeping Jest from exiting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52701206/jest-has-detected-the-following-1-open-handle-potentially-keeping-jest-from-exit)

How can I get it to run successfully (200 response) and not bail because of open handles?

```
import axios from 'axios';

describe('Cart Manipulation', () => {
  let oc_token: string;

  beforeAll(() => {
    oc_token = "eyJblahblahblah"
  });

  it('user can create a cart', async () => {
    const response = await axios.put(
      'https://api.urltogoto',
      { 
        'Accept': 'application/json', 
        // 'Authorization': 'Bearer eyJblahblahblah'
        'Authorization': oc_token
      }
    );
    console.log(response);
    expect(response.status).toBe(200);
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution, I don't know what specific change made the difference, but a lot of futzing around produced this:

```
import axios, {AxiosRequestConfig} from 'axios';

describe('Cart Manipulation', () => {
  it('user can create a cart', async () => {
    let config = {
      method: 'put',
      maxBodyLength: Infinity,
      url: 'https://api.blablahurl',
      headers: { 
        'Accept': 'application/json', 
        'Authorization': 'Bearer sillylittletoken'
      }
    } as AxiosRequestConfig;

    const response = await axios.request(config)
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
      expect(response.status).toEqual(200);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
  });
});
```